# Python's shebang evaluates to different Python version than the same path used in the console

Tags: python, debian, linux-mint, shebang, pyenv

Today is my first day with Python and I am using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to deal with Python's versions. I successfully installed the latest version (3.6.3) and set it as global with

```
pyenv global 3.6.3
```

Now when executing in terminal

```
/usr/bin/env python
```

I get the expected correct response

```
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct 24 2017, 02:48:04) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

However the problem I have is that shebang I use in my script file has the same `/usr/bin/env python` path but who knows why it still evaluates to the preinstalled system's version of Python which is 2.7.6.

I am checking the version used by script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print(sys.version)
```

and what I get printed by the browser (using Apache2) is

```
2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) [GCC 4.8.4]
```

I was restarting apache, playing with pyenv configs, googling for any hints but no success.

Anybody has any idea what is wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544#39713544) claims that pyenv is deprecated for 3.6+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyenv` allows you to set the used Python version on a **per user basis**.

So if you set it to `3.6.3` for the user `misza`, other users (like `www-data`) will not be affected.

The webserver will most likely run as a special user (usually `www-data`), so any changes you do to your personal settings will have no effect on whatever apache sees.

Having said that, I really think it is a bad idea to use `pyenv` on something like a server in any case: *your* script might not be the only one that uses a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang. It might also not be the only one that relies on being called by a specific Python version (and the odds have it, that most scripts with `#!/usr/bin/env python` are actually Python2.7 scripts).

So if you really want your script to run under a specific Python version, you should use that specific Python version in the shebang:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3.7
```

or even

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3.8
```